# Unable to Serialise Graph with base class and derived class properties using GraphMLExtensions

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, graphml, quickgraph

I have a custom implementation of **Graph** using **Quick graph**(NuGet Package). When I'm trying to Serialise this graph object using **GraphMLExtensions**, I'm able to Serialise only **base class** propeties but not both **base class** & derived class.

Please help me out on this issue.

Thanks in advance.